adb over bluetooth to wearos watch from ubuntu?
i have a WearOS watch that supports bluetooth debugging but not wifi debugging. How can I get the adb command line program on Ubuntu to connect to it by bluetooth?
I can pair with the watch, gets its bluetooth  6 bytes address and even a pairing code. But how can I get an adb connect to happen? Adb connect wants an IP address and there is none.

What do you want to do after connecting it via adb?

Being specific as to what Ubuntu product you're using may have helped, ie. are you using a Ubuntu Core system?  Server or text interface only system? Desktop system with GUI?  and what release?

Is there some software on the computer you are supposed to run?

I wanted to be able to use adb on Linux to sideload an apk on the phone. "Developer Options" on the phone let me select debug over bluetooth, but not debug over wifi. So I was trying to find out how to connect the Linux adb to the phone by bluetooth.
The watch has a preference to use bluetooth for connectivity and to save power only turns on wifi if bluetooth is unavailable. So all I had to do was turn off bluetooth on the watch, and then the developer option for debug over wifi became available.
So, I still don't know how to use bluetooth for adb from Linux to the watch, but wifi is a better option anyway.
